# What should be in portfolio for jquery developer

Tags: portfolio

Jquery is part of many bigger things. Alone it is not much. So how do i demonstrate my jquery skills efficently.

What qualities Senior developers are looking in of a jquery developer when they are hiring one.

I can think on top of my head.

- Understanding Javascript well.
- Understanding jquery's plugins or make them (sadly i can't, does that mean i suck as jquery developer).
- Dom Manipulation, Event Binding, Ajax..

Please Help..I am trying to add 2 big and 15 small examples that showcase my abilities as Jquery developer so what is that you would like to see in a portfolio of a Jquery Dev.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you visit popular freelancing websites like freelancer.com or odesk.com or elance.com and find their top jQuery developers and see what they have listed into their portfolio. Since themselves being top developers, they will have good portfolio.

That is much quicker and better way then waiting for such global reply here. If you would have questions after examining their portfolios, then come back here and ask more specific question. I am sure someone will reply. Developers are busy people and they tend not to spend their precious time answering global questions.

Comment: i just checked they didn't seem to have portfolio but their reputation as the main point you know 90 reviews with 5 ratings

Comment: Check odesk. They should have it.